# EF6: Check if previous DB entry is the same as new object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is C# and EF6. I have a function that sometimes runs twice (by design). As part of that function I'd like to check if a new object is the same as the newest entry in the DB **and** was created within the past 3 seconds. The main problem is that the `Id` column is auto-filled when the item is fetched, and EF6 won't let me clear it or set it to a standard number since it's the key property.

I think I can figure out the logic to check the time, but what would be the correct way to check if the two items are otherwise the same?

Comment: What "the same" is meant? How to compare these objects?

Comment: Equivalent. Not different.